# how to deploy changes with chef's deploy resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I've got another question at [chef deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871124/chef-deployment) that is perhaps a little too broad in scope. so i'll ask a more specific question here:

how do i deploy code changes with chef's [Deploy Resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource) after the server has been set up. perhaps i'm just used to my current capistrano workflow ("git push && cap deploy") ... but the best i can tell is that after i commit my changes i'm supposed to ssh into the server and run "sudo chef-client"? something about that feels wrong. is there no cap equivalent, i.e. "chef deploy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Chef Server, you can use `knife ssh` to search for a subset of nodes to SSH to and run Chef Client.

```
% knife ssh "role:my_app" "sudo chef-client"
```

You can also run Chef Client on an interval as a daemon, or a cron job. You may be interested in the [chef-client](http://ckbk.it/chef-client) and [application](http://ckbk.it/application) cookbooks by Opscode for these topics.

Comment: what if I do not want every code commit to be deployed ? I'm running chef-client as a daemon , and I do not have ssh permissions into the client. I have access only the the chef-server. How about that case?

Comment: use the deploy_revision provider for the deploy resource. http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html